# AWS Permissions to delete a CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a CloudFormation stack that includes EC2 instances, IAM roles and an autoscaling group. This is a transient stack that performs a load test in a target ALB. Once the test completes (it is limited in time), results are sent and this stack should be removed.

Right now I create the stack from my computer using my credentials, although my final intention is to have this automated in a CodePipeline step.

I was trying to make the stack to call for his own deletion using the CLI:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ${AWS::StackName} --region ${AWS::Region}
```

The EC2 instance (part of this stack) running this command have this role:

```
 WorkerNodeRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: LoadTestNodeRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
              - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole   
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LoadTestNodeRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Resource: '*'
              Action: iam:PassRole
            - Effect: Allow 
              Resource: !Sub arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stack/${AWS::StackName}/*
              Action:
                - cloudformation:DeleteStack
```

I was hoping this to be enough to delete the stack, but it is complaining about permissions to remove the individual elements of the stack. For example:

```
API: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroup User: arn:aws:sts::(account):assumed-role/LoadtestNodeRole/(instance) is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
```

How can I give a role permission to do a `cloudformation:DeleteStack` on a specific stack to delete everything included?

For example, this stack fails to delete itself for the said reasons:

```
Description: Autodelete test

Resources:

  WorkerNodeRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: NodeRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
              - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole   
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: NodeRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Resource: '*'
              Action: iam:PassRole
            - Effect: Allow 
              Resource: !Sub arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stack/${AWS::StackName}/*
              Action:
                - cloudformation:DeleteStack

  WorkerNodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - !Ref WorkerNodeRole

  MasterNode:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref WorkerNodeInstanceProfile
      ImageId: ami-0be2609ba883822ec
      InstanceType: t2.small
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub 
            | 
            #!/bin/bash
            aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ${AWS::StackName} --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summary: To make your call delete stack call work, you need to amend the policy for all the resources(ASG,EC2,IAM + Cloudformation) you have in the stack, in your case your ec2 instance role.

The explanation for error:

Just to delete the stack you need the following permissions:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:1234567890:stack/case-test3-stack/53a723c0-f413-11ea-8958"
            }
        ]
    }
```

> I have a CloudFormation stack that includes EC2 instances, IAM roles, and an autoscaling group.

So everything is in one stack and when you try to delete the stack, Cloudformation goes sequentially from top to bottom unless there are some depends on clauses added to the definition for everything in the stack for deletion.

You can't selectively delete the resources by using the [delete-stack](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack.html)

Plus the instance making the call for deletion has only deletion permissions for cloudformation stack but your cloudformation stack has ASG and other resources as well.So it fails.

Like I created this stack

```
    $ cat minimal-cfn.yml
    Resources:
    Bucket:
        Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    BucketName:
        Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
        Properties:
        Description: !Sub 'S3 Bucket from stack ${AWS::StackName}'
        Name: '/s3bucket/main/bucket-name'
        Type: String
        Value: !Ref Bucket
```

And my role has only permissions for the delete stack as I mentioned above in the policy, now I try to delete the stack and I get the error

```
    $ aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name adsadasdasdas

     User: arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/testrole1/s3-access-example is 
    not authorized to perform: ssm:DeleteParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:1234567890:parameter/s3bucket/main/bucket-name
    (Service: AmazonSSM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 785ba9ad-e1b4-4d4b-aef4-5bea51481a87; Proxy: null)
```

because the role doesn't have the permission for deleting the resources inside the stack.

Comment: how is this different to what I have explained I have done?

Comment: @vtscop I tried to describe why your delete-stack calls fails and what is teh strategy in that call for deleting the resource. So you can't do the delete-stack operation as well when the resources you are trying to delete are the ones where you are trying to make the call for deletion, in your case the instance and the reason why you are getting the error for autoscaling permissions because the ec2 instance's role is being used for deletion and as the stack is being deleted as a whole, so it needs autoscaling permissions as well.

Comment: I guess I cannot delete anything without permissions for the individual items :( Thanks